# Has anyone used patTemplate and should I be concerned to work on a project using it?

Tags: php

I'm quoting on a project that is using [patTemplate](http://trac.php-tools.net/patTemplate). I'm wondering if anyone has used it and what they think of it?

I'm not a fan of PHP templating systems because PHP is basically a templating system itself, but wondering how bad patTemplate is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my experiences:

1. Bad documented project
2. Looks very inactive for now
3. Oversized files
4. Unnecessary includes

IMO use any other template system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) which is also used by [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) or write your own as I do.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the template-wars days, patTemplate was one of the real contestants. I don't think it sees much use today, but it's probably fairly stable and feature complete. I wouldn't pick it as first choice, but I don't think it's worse than anything else. The most prominent feature of patTemplate (If I recall correctly), is that it's xml-based, although I'm unsure about what benefit that gives.